# Unity Quiz Game image on questions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I input image to be my questions on my quiz game app. I've managed to have the image script but I can't see any images

Here is my code for the Game Controller which holds the data of the game.
Here's an image of the Game Controller 
[Game Controller will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgbQd.png)

```
 public Sprite quizImage;
    public TSSimpleObjectPool answerButtonObjectPool;
    public Text questionText;
    public Text scoreDisplay;
    public Text timeRemainingDisplay;
    public Transform answerButtonParent;

public GameObject questionDisplay;
public GameObject roundEndDisplay;
public Text highScoreDisplay;
```

The problem is image does not show when i run the app. What is the problem?

Comment: Why on earth are you mentioning that it's a quiz game app? Just give the code, say you're working with unity, and explain that you're having trouble with an image. I don't understand what the problem is, by the way. You should clarify what's wrong. And read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want to display the images that is what I only want nothing else, because everytime i run the game no image is display on the game

Comment: Well, then you need to choose what image to show and put the Sprite on `Quiz Image`. It kind of hints on that since it says "None" next to it.

Comment: I already done that but no image has shown.. do i need to put them into an array ?

Comment: What did you put in? If it's a Sprite and it's not transparent or something, it should work. Create a new game with nothing else in it, only have a gameobject in the scene and test.

Comment: Okay so I have a prefabs and I put those images in it. I have a 5 game rounds of the game. so I need 5 Images in 1 Scene.. Do you think an array is not needed or code in c#?

Comment: The object will hold 1 image at a time. You'll change the image each round. You should store all images inside an array but maybe not inside the gameobject.

Answer (score 0):

**"Image doesn't show" could mean multiple things. You really need to clarify.**

But here are some quick fixes from my experience. (Common error: "Image doesn't show")

a)
Make sure you look at the parameters when looking at Unity. When you superimpose images in unity (ie putting a background with a image), it's a common issue that sometimes images cover each other. You have like 5 images/text in your picture... make sure your paying attention to z values.

b) You need to looking into prefabs. IE dragging an image into the hierarchy and dragging it back to assets usually does the trick. Get the prefab -> drag it into the public gameobject. Judging by how you haven't plugged in a sprite in your image means you can't to figure out how ton drag objects in.

Some documentation on prefabs
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html

c) You're mixing up Sprites and GameObjects together. Look up differences between the two and post again.

d) Make sure you are not plugging in a blank sprite. If you want to use sprites, make sure you know how to attach to image to them. You can follow this tutorial down here.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html

Second of all, sprites are used in unity 2D, not unity 3D. They are 2D graphical objects... stop mixing up the two.

Hope this helped.